# Finding a relative minimum. (I don't understand how its possible for the answer sheet to be correct)

Tags: calculus

> The function $f$ is given by $f\left(x\right) = 9x^{2/3}+3x-6$ has a relative minimum at $x =$
>
> (A) $-8\;\;$   (B) $-\sqrt[3]{2}\;\;\;$    (C) $-1\;\;\;\;$ (D)$-1/8\;\;\;$  (E) $0$

**The answer sheet says $x=0$ is correct**
*Note this class only works with real numbers*

I took the first derivative and set it equal to zero in order to find the critical points.

$f^{\prime}\left(x\right) = 6x^{-1/3}+3$ equals zero at $x^{-1/3}=-2\, \rightarrow x^{1/3} = -1/2$ thus $x = -1/8$.

Now use the second derivative to see if max/min.

$f^{\prime\prime}\left(x\right) = -2x^{-4/3}$  at the critical point found above results in a complex number.

Where did I take a wrong turn at Albuquerque?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a mistake when you found the CP. The critical points are points where $f'(x)=0$ **OR** $f'(x)$ does not exists.

$f'(x)=0$ implies $x=-\frac18$.

$f'(x)$ DNE implies $x=0$.

Thus there are two critical points.

Also $-2 (-\frac{1}{8})^\frac{-4}{3}=-32$ is not complex.

Comment: I pluged the number into wolframalpha and it reported a complex number.  Could you show me how to find it?

Comment: $\left( -\frac{1}{8} \right)^{1/3}=-\frac{1}{2}$. And $(-\frac{1}{2})^{-4}=(-2)^4=16$. @MaoYiyi

Comment: The problem is that there are three potential complex third roots of a number, and WA choses one in some way (I think the principal branch). But in your situation, there is one which is real but not the chosen one.... For various reasons computers sometimes lead to the wrong answer ;)

Comment: $f\left(-1/8\right) = -33/8$??

Comment: @MaoYiyi yes....

Answer (score 1):

(As an aside, if possible, I would make a rough plot of the function first.)

You need to check where the function is differentiable and check points where it fails to be differentiable. The function $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Here is a trick that simplifies the problem a bit:
Look at $\phi(x) = f(x^3)$ to see why $x=0$ is a local minimum (since $x \mapsto x^3$ is a bijection).

If you grind through the details, you get $\phi(x) = 3(x+1)(x^2+2x-2)$. We have $\phi'(x) = 9x (x+2)$, and $\phi''(x) = 18(x+1)$. Hence $\phi'(0) = 0$ and $\phi''(0) >0$. Hence $\phi$ (and hence $f$) has a local minimum at $x=0$.

The local minimum **value** at $x=0$ is $f(0) = -6$.

Comment: why doesn't $f\left(0\right) = -6$?

Comment: It does equal $-6$. Perhaps you are confusing the local minimum value with the local minimizer?

Comment: The annoying feature of functions like this containing fractional exponents is that they can introduce cusps ("kinks") in the continuous curve for the function.  So the first derivative there is undefined and the standard "first and second derivative tests" for critical points will be of no help.  If $f(x)$ _is_ defined at such a point, you must investigate the behavior of the function in that neighborhood to see what sort of extremum it represents.

Comment: True; but often for homework style problems you can 'work out the kink' (at least locally) with judicious bijections.